# Command not found : Error: Process completed with exit code 127

Tags: github, github-actions

I am running this workflow. The same workflow was running without any issues earlier but suddenly it's giving me the mentioned error when I changed the `metadata4.vql` file contents. Any suggestion/help would be highly appreciated as I am very new to GitHub actions.
Thanks in advance!

**Error at step: ouput the get_value**

**Workflow:**

```yaml
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: extract vql for the target db
        run: /opt/denodo/bin/export.sh -l admin -p admin -h 10.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/ci_cd_main -f metadata4.vql -P includeProperties=yes -P includeCreateDatabase=yes -P replaceExistingElements=yes

      - name: converting vqltobase64
        run: | 
            echo "get_value=$(base64 -w 0 metadata4.vql | cut -c 5- | iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-5)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      
      - name: ouput the get_value
        run: ${{env.get_value}}
        
      - name: revision creation using solution manager api
        run: curl --location 'https://10.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/revisions/loadFromVQL' --header 'Content-type:application/json' --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx' --data '{"name":"test_rev-007","description":"revision_creation","content":"'"${{ env.get_value }}"'"}' > at.json
        
      - name: get revision id
        run:
           echo "get_revision_id= $(jq '.id' at.json)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
           
      - name: print revision id
        run : echo "${{env.get_revision_id }}"
        
      - name: deploy to target env
        run: curl --location 'https://10.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/deployments' --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx' --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --data '{"revisionIds":[${{env.get_revision_id}}],"environmentId":82,"description":"test"}'`
```

Comment: Are you missing an `echo` in here? `run: echo ${{env.get_value}}`, I suspect `get_value` ahs bene empty or contained a valid executable and it no lo longer does.